# How can I use induction solve this?

Tags: induction

How can I show/solve this? I've tried by using the basis step and the inductive step, but just can't seem to get it right.

$$\forall(n \geq 0)(4\mid(9^n − 5^n)).$$

Comment: do you mean $9^n-5^n$ by any  chance?

Comment: Yeah, sorry - overlooked that

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/283056/induction-proof-help-number-theory-george-e-andrews-1-1-3/283065#283065) is helpful.

Answer (score 4):

You can use

$$9^n-5^n=(9-5)(9^{n-1}+9^{n-2}\cdot 5+..+5^{n-1})$$

This solution has hidden induction in it.

Alternately, by induction:

$$9^{n+1}-5^{n+1}=9^{n+1}-9^{n}\cdot 5+9^{n}5-5^{n+1}=9^n\cdot 4+5(9^n-5^n)$$

use $P(n)$ and done.

Answer (score 1):

$(a^n-b^n)(a+b)=a^{n+1}-b^{n+1}+ab(a^{n-1}-b^{n-1})$

$\implies a^{n+1}-b^{n+1}=(a^n-b^n)(a+b)-ab(a^{n-1}-b^{n-1})$

If $a,b,n$ are positive integers,

if $(a-b)$ divides  $(a^n-b^n)$ and $(a^{n-1}-b^{n-1}),$ it will divide $a^{n+1}-b^{n+1}$

Now for $n=0, a^0-b^0=0$ which is divisible by $(a-b)$ for $ab(a-b)\ne0$

for $n=1, a^1-b^1=a-b$

Alternatively,  the way N.S. has solved it : 
$a^{n+1}-b^{n+1}=a^n(a-b)+b(a^n-b^n)$

Comment: The latter is a special case of the proof of the Congruence Product Rule - see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{eqnarray}{\bf Hint}&&\rm m\mid\ \  \color{#C00}{a^k\!-\!b^k}\:\  and\:\  m\mid \color{#0A0}{a-b} \\ \Rightarrow\: &&\rm m\mid (\color{#C00}{a^k\!-b^k})\,a\,+\,b^k(\color{#0A0}{a-b})\, =\: a^{k+1}\!-b^{k+1}\end{eqnarray}$

**Note** $\ $ The above proof is essentially a special case of that for the **Congruence Product Rule.** Below are proofs of this product rule proof expressed in both divisibility and congruence form, $ $ using the standard notation: $\rm\  \ a\mid b \ :=\ a\,$ divides $\rm\, b,\ $ and $\rm\ \, a\equiv b\ \ (mod\ m) \iff m\mid a-b$

$\begin{eqnarray}
\rm {\bf Lemma}\ \   &\rm m\ \ |&\rm\ \, X\!-\!x\quad\  \& &&\rm\! m\ |\: Y\!-\!y \ \Rightarrow\ m\:|\!\!&&\rm XY - \: xy\\ \\
\rm {\bf Proof}\ \ \ \ \ &\rm m\ \ |&\rm (X\!-\!\color{#c00}x)\:\color{#c00}Y\  \,+   &&\rm\, \color{#c00}x\ (\color{#c00}Y\!-\!y)\ \ \ \ = &&\rm XY - \: xy \\
\\
\rm {\bf Lemma}\ \ &         &\rm\ \, X\equiv x\quad\ \  \& &&\rm\quad\  Y\equiv y \ \ \ \ \Rightarrow\ &&\rm XY\equiv xy\\ \\
\rm {\bf Proof}\ \ \ \ \ &0\equiv& \rm (X\!-\!\color{#c00}x)\:\color{#c00}Y\,\   + &&\rm\, \color{#C00}x\ (\color{#c00}Y\!-\!y)\ \ \ \ \equiv &&\rm XY - \: xy \\
\end{eqnarray}$