# The identity $a^n-b^n=(a-b) (\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a^ib^{n-1-i})$

Tags: real-analysis, summation, induction, geometric-progressions

How do I use finite induction to prove that
$$a^n-b^n=(a-b) (\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a^ib^{n-1-i}), \forall a,b\in \Bbb{R}\space \text{and} \space \forall n \in \Bbb{N}?$$
Ok, for $n=2$ it's fine. $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(b+a)=(a-b)(\sum_{i=0}^1a^ib^{n-1-i})$.
Right, then suppose the equality valid for n. But, how to handle with $a^{n+1}-b^{n+1}$? How to use the induction hypothesis here?

Need some help!

If this question has already been answered, please, give me the link... Sorry about that.

Comment: I think that using induction isn't very good idea.

Comment: @Antony It is standard. Check [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/283056/induction-proof-that-xn-yn-x-yxn-1xn-2y-ldotsxyn-2yn-1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

Let $S{}={}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a^ib^{n-1-i}$. Compute $aS-bS$.

Comment: Oh! Thanks @ki3i! It seems that this proves the assertion without even using induction. Very useful. Thanks!

Comment: @AndersonFelipeViveiros, You are welcome.