# How do I prove that $x^n-y^n=(x-y)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+\dotsb+xy^{n-2}+y^{n-1})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, geometric-progressions

I am unsuccessfully attempting a problem from Spivak's popular book 'Calculus' 3rd edition. The problem requires proof for the following equation: 
$$x^n-y^n=(x-y)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+\dotsb+xy^{n-2}+y^{n-1})$$
The solution to the problem, contained in the answer book, is as follows:
\begin{align*}
x^n-y^n &= (x-y)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+\dotsb+xy^{n-2}+y^{n-1})\\
&= x(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+\dotsb+xy^{n-2}+y^{n-1})\\
&\qquad -[y(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+{...}+xy^{n-2}+y^{n-1})]&\Rightarrow \mathbf{Equation1}\\
&=x^n+x^{n-1}y+\dotsb+x^2y^{n-2}+xy^{n-1}\\
&\qquad -[x^{n-1}y+x^{n-2}y^2+xy^{n-1}+y^n]&\Rightarrow \mathbf{Equation2}\\
&=x^n-y^n
\end{align*}

While I believe that the distributive law was used to arrive at **Equation 1**, I do not understand how **Equation 2** was arrived at.

I have tried to solve this independently to no avail. I cannot seem to understand how $x^n$ and $y^n$ came about in **Equation 2** for example.

To summarise the question, what principle was **Equation 2** based upon? And how was this applied in the above problem.

Comment: Use induction on n

Comment: Please verify the edit.

Comment: Btw you are missing a y.

Comment: Now this is probably silly, but if you wanted to, you could consider the polynomial $f(x,y)=x^n-y^n$, which has obvious root/factor $(x-y)$, so upon dividing, you can use Viete's formulas to find all the other coefficients.

Comment: See also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/283056/induction-proof-that-xn-yn-x-yxn-1xn-2y-ldotsxyn-2yn-1) and other posts [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/283056).

Comment: If the purpose of this question is not to get *some proof* of this fact, but to get explanation of *the specific proof* you copied from this book, you should probably use ([tag:proof-explanation]) tag to indicate this. See the [tag-info](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/proof-explanation/info).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving $x^n - y^n = (x-y)(x^{n-1} + x^{n-2} y + ... + x y^{n-2} + y^{n-1})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117660/proving-xn-yn-x-yxn-1-xn-2-y-x-yn-2-yn-1)

Answer (score 2):

I like using $\sum$ like this:

$\begin{array}\\
(x-y)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+\dotsb+xy^{n-2}+y^{n-1})
&=(x-y)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^{n-1-k} y^k\\
&=x\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^{n-1-k} y^k-y\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^{n-1-k} y^k\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^{n-k} y^k-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^{n-1-k} y^{k+1}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^{n-k} y^k-\sum_{k=1}^{n} x^{n-k} y^{k}\\
&=x^n+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} x^{n-k} y^k-\left(y^n+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} x^{n-k} y^{k}\right)\\
&=x^n-y^n+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} x^{n-k} y^k-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} x^{n-k} y^{k}\\
&=x^n-y^n\\
\end{array}
$

Answer (score 1):

You have an error; it should be $x^n - y^n = (x-y)(x^{n-1} + x^{n-2}y + ... + xy^{n-2} + y^{n-1})$. Just distribute.

Comment: Honestly more comment worthy.  And already mentioned in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to prove first
$$1-t^n=(1-t)(1+t+\dots+t^{n-1})$$
by induction.

The formula is trivial for $n=1$. So suppose the formula is valid for some $n\ge 1$, and consider the exponent $n+1$.
\begin{align}
1-t^{n+1}&=(1-t^n)+(t^n-t^{n+1})\\
&=(1-t)(1+t+\dots+t^{n-1})+t^n(1-t)\\
&=(1-t)(1+t+\dots+t^{n-1+t^n}),
\end{align}
 which proves the inductive step.

Now for the general formula: set $y=tx$, and substitute in the expression:
\begin{align}
x^n-y^n&=x^n(1-t^n)=x^n(1-t)(1+t+\dots+t^{n-1})\\
&=x(1-t)\cdot x^{n-1}(1+t+\dots+t^{n-1})\\
&=(x-tx)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}tx+\dots +(tx)^{n-1})\\
&=(x-y)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+\dots +y^{n-1}).
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

> The step from equation 1 to equation 2 uses both the *[distributive law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property#Definition)* as well as the *[commutative law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property#Definition)*.

In order to better see what's going on, we look at small special cases $n=2,3$. We also use somewhat more detailed transformations.

> **n=2:**
>   \begin{align*}
> (x-y)\left(x^{1}+y^1\right)&=x\left(x^{1}+y^1\right)-y\left(x^1+y^1\right)\\
> &=\left(x\cdot x^1+x\cdot y^1\right)-\left(y\cdot x^1+y\cdot y^1\right)\\
> &=\left(x^2+xy\right)-\left(yx+y^2\right)\\
> &=x^2+xy-yx-y^2\\
> &=x^2-y^2
> \end{align*}
>
> **n=3:**
>   \begin{align*}
> &(x-y)\left(x^{2}+x^1y^1+y^2\right)\\
> &\qquad=x\left(x^{2}+x^1y^1+y^2\right)-y\left(x^{2}+x^1y^1+y^2\right)\\
> &\qquad=\left(x\cdot x^2+x\cdot x^1y^1+x\cdot y^2\right)-\left(y\cdot x^2+y\cdot x^1y^1+y\cdot y^2\right)\\
> &\qquad=\left(x^3+x^2y+xy^2\right)-\left(yx^2+y^2x+y^3\right)\\
> &\qquad=x^3+x^2y+xy^2-yx^2-y^2x-y^3\\
> &\qquad=x^3-y^3
> \end{align*}
>
> **general n:**
>   \begin{align*}
> &(x-y)\left(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y^1+\cdots+xy^{n-1}+y^{n-1}\right)\\
> &\qquad=x\left(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y^1+\cdots\cdots\cdot\cdot+xy^{n-1}+y^{n-1}\right)\\
> &\qquad\qquad\qquad\ \ -y\left(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y^1+\cdots\cdots+xy^{n-1}+y^{n-1}\right)\\
> &\qquad=\left(x\cdot x^{n-1}+\color{blue}{x\cdot x^{n-2}y^1}+\cdots\cdots+x\cdot xy^{n-1}+\color{blue}{x\cdot y^{n-1}}\right)\\
> &\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad-\left(\color{red}{y\cdot x^{n-1}}+y\cdot x^{n-2}y^1+\cdots\cdots\cdot+\color{red}{y\cdot xy^{n-1}}+y\cdot y^{n-1}\right)\\
> &\qquad=\left(x^{n}+ \color{blue}{x^{n-1}y}+\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots+x^2y^{n-1}+\color{blue}{xy^{n-1}}\right)\\
> &\qquad\qquad\ -\left( \color{red}{y x^{n-1}}+x^{n-2}y^2+\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdot+\color{red}{xy^{n-1}}+y^{n}\right)\\
> &\qquad=x^{n}\;+ \color{blue}{x^{n-1}y}+\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots+x^2y^{n-1}+\color{blue}{xy^{n-1}}\\
> &\qquad\qquad\ \ -\color{red}{x^{n-1}y}-x^{n-2}y^2-\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots-\color{red}{xy^{n-1}}-y^{n}\\
> &\qquad=x^n-y^n
> \end{align*}

Comment: Thanks very much @markuscheuer. This was really helpful.

Comment: @od320: You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Equation 1 by distributive law and Equation 2 also by distributive law (just expand the expressions)

Another method: Use polynomial long division on
$$(x^n-y^n):(x-y)$$.